Building a predicate out of a predicate for nested containers
I'm trying to build an associative container with a customizable comparison predicate and I'm internally using a set to store some of the data. It should be pretty straightforward, I just need to pass along the predicate:
template <typename T, typename TComparePredicate  = std::less<T>>
class MyContainer
{
public:
    MyContainer(const TComparePredicate& predicate = TComparePredicate()) : _internalSet(predicate) { ... }
    ...
private:
    std::set<T, TComparePredicate> _internalSet;
};

Unfortunately, my real case is more complex. I need to store other data in the set (don't ask why, it makes sense in this context), so my code looks more like this:
template <typename T, typename V, typename TComparePredicate = std::less<T>>
class MyContainer
{
public:
    MyContainer(const TComparePredicate& predicate = TComparePredicate()) : _internalSet(???) { ... }
    ...
private:
    std::set<std::pair<T, V>, ???> _internalSet;
};

I still need the set to be ordered only considering the T value, so my simple solution is to create a functor that stores the real predicate and dispatches calls to it:
template <typename T, typename V, typename Predicate>
struct PairForwardingFunctor
{
    PairForwardingFunctor(const Predicate& predicate = Predicate()) : _predicate(predicate) { }
    bool operator()(const std::pair<T, V>& lhs, const std::pair<T, V>& rhs) { return _predicate(lhs.first, rhs.first); }

private:
    Predicate _predicate;
};

But I feel uneasy with this solution. I haven't still compiler-explored this (if it can even get down there), but I have a feeling there is a level of indirection that is not optimizable.
Is there a better approach to this?

At this point, couldn't you swap over to a std::map<T, V> ? It would have the same semantics as a std::set<std::pair<T,V>> for your use case.

Why using PairForwardingFunctor<T, V, Predicate> instead of just PairForwardingFunctor<T, V>? If you wanna use some contexts in operator(), the lambda expression is a better choice than PairForwardingFunctor.

@Botje std::map<T, V> is not the same as std::set<std::pair<T, V>>. The former doesn't allow multiple values of V combined with a single T value (i.e. (1, 2), (1, 3)), and doesn't support looking up a (T, V) pair directly.

Side note: you could put the template parameter TComparePredicate being a template template parameter like template<typename> class TComparePredicate. Then you wouldn't have to repeat type T, ie. std::less instead of std::less<T> for instance.

@TimothyLiu the std::set with a custom comparator that only considers the first element of the pair doesn't support that either. It will see (1,2) and (1,3) as the same element. And you also can't directly look up a pair since the comparator only checks the first element. Unless I'm missing something, this set is basically modeling std::map. If multiple values were needed, there's std::multimap.

@TimothyLiu Given that the comparator ignores V, you can pass in any V to test set membership of (T, V). In fact, the only way to get that V back out is  *s.find(some_t,V{}). Then m[some_t] is a whole lot more approachable IMO :)

@Botje I'm considering using a map, but that's not really the point of my question. I was more interested in how to, for lack of a better expression, "forward a predicate" in the most efficient way

@edrezen I've never actually used of template template parameters, but looking at std containers I think you're dismissing function pointers as potential comparing predicates

While working on a similar problem, I found out a solution which should be a little more efficient, despite being more verbose:
template <typename T, typename V, typename Predicate, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct PairForwardingFunctor : private Predicate
{
    PairForwardingFunctor(const Predicate& predicate = Predicate()) : Predicate(predicate) { }
    bool operator()(const std::pair<T, V>& lhs, const std::pair<T, V>& rhs) { return Predicate::operator()(lhs.first, rhs.first); }
};

template <typename T, typename V, typename Predicate>
struct PairForwardingFunctor<T, V, Predicate, std::void_t<std::is_pointer<Predicate>::type>
{
    PairForwardingFunctor(const Predicate& predicate) : _predicate(predicate) { }
    bool operator()(const std::pair<T, V>& lhs, const std::pair<T, V>& rhs) { return _predicate(lhs.first, rhs.first); }

private:
    Predicate _predicate;
};

This avoids any internal object creation for lambda and function objects, which are way more likely to be optimized away. Function pointers are still stored, as I don't think it's possible to do otherwise with those.
It's obviously still a stub, as it needs more care about transparent comparison, but if nobody has a better idea I'm going to choose this answer in a few days.

If you believe that this works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests if you can) along with its motivation over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code does, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".
